# Vue.js v-html not rendering line breaks (<br>) in dynamically injected HTML content

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a component that highlights code:

```
<template>
  <div class="mx-auto h-[30rem] w-[30rem] border-2 border-black">
    <code-highlight language="javascript">
      <code>
        <p v-html="html"></p>
      </code>
    </code-highlight>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import CodeHighlight from 'vue-code-highlight/src/CodeHighlight.vue'
import 'vue-code-highlight/themes/duotone-sea.css'
import 'vue-code-highlight/themes/window.css'
const props = defineProps(['html'])
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

and the use:

```
<code-example :html=html>
              </code-example>
```

html is

```
<p><em>[a-zA-Z]&nbsp;&nbsp;</em>any letter a-z and A-Z<br> [0-9] means any number<br>[a-z0-9] any letter a-z or number 0-8<br>[a-zA-Z0-9_] any leeter a-z and A_Z, any number 0-9 and "_"</p>
```

and any of the `<br>` tags are not executed. The tags is a one long line, the component doesnt change its size, it only has a 10% of a div.  Why `<br>` tags or `"/n"` are not executed and the component doesn't change hight?

I tried changing `<p>` to `<div>` or different structure but it didn't work...

edit:
thanks sir for answer, but it didnt help. If i copy and paste the code from https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-code-highlight-example-63h5m?file=/src/components/ComponentExample.vue on a blank page, it still doesnt wrap...

Comment: check your styles for `<code>` maybe there're some white space rules applied

Comment: thanks sir for answer, but it didnt help. If i copy and paste the code from https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-code-highlight-example-63h5m?file=/src/components/ComponentExample.vue on a blank page, it still doesnt wrap...